# Bug with :active style in Safari v.11.0.1

Tags: css, safari, css-selectors

I'm having an issue when I add **:active** selector to any element since I updated my laptop's macOS to High Sierra and therefore **Safari** to its **11.0.1 version**.

The issue is that when I click the element with the :active selector the :active styles remains in the element unless I move the cursor, there is no the desired 'click' effect I'm looking for.

In the rest of the browsers and previous versions of Safari this issue doesn't happen and the effect works perfect. Does anybody experience the same issue or know how to resolve it?

To see this bug happen I created a pen **BUT** you will need to change the view to **Debug Mode**. Funnily the bug doesn't show in the rest of view options.

`.button:active {
  transform: translate(2px, 2px);
}`
https://codepen.io/guisopo/pen/vedNZW

Comment: I'm running into this same thing, you haven't happened to come across a solution?